# Objective C try parse boolean

Tags: objective-c, parsing, nsstring, boolean, tryparse

I would like to know how, in Objective-C, how to tell if a string represents a boolean value. The `[string boolValue]` method will not work, because when I try to parse a string like `[@"ERROR" boolValue]` it returns NO instead of throwing an exception. In C#, I could do something like: `if (Boolean.TryParse(string, out bool))`, but this is not available in Objective-C as far as I know because the `BOOL` type is not object oriented. Will I have to write my own `BOOL` parser class? Or is there something I am missing (`NSScanner` for instance)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation, `boolValue` "returns YES on encountering one of "Y", "y", "T", "t", or a digit 1-9—the method ignores any trailing characters. Returns NO if the receiver doesn’t begin with a valid decimal text representation of a number."

If you're looking for something different, you'll need to write a little utility or use [a category](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Articles/ocCategories.html) to get the job done.

If it's something quick, you could even resort to using NSString's `-isEqualToString:` method.

Comment: So I need to make my own custom parser?

Comment: That's what I have done, and I do believe that it will work for my situation, thank you for the response.